# does one class SVM (SVDD) detect Novelty or Outlier and what are the supporting vectors of SVDD

Tags: svm, outliers

From my understanding of `one class SVM (SVDD)`, the training data should all be the normal points (don't include outliers). Then a new point is added, we can use the trained SVDD to determine whether it is a Novelty (in the sphere or out the sphere). And SVDD cannot detect the outliers in the training data before training. Do I understand correctly for the above statement?

Second, what's the supporting vectors of SVDD? The points in the training data with the non-zero Lagrange multipliers same as SVM?

Comment: What question are you trying to ask in the first paragraph? It sounds more like a claim, than a question. The second paragraph should be posted as separate question, since it doesn't seem to be related with the previous one.

Comment: @Tim sorry, I just want to check that whether I understand correctly for the first paragraph.

Comment: Can you please include that clarification as an edit to the post? Not everybody reads comments.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have updated  the question